# Generated Custom Managed Object Class does not build

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, core-data

I have built an data model in Xcode and I have generated a custom managed object class from one of the entities in the model. I am not sure why but I don't think the custom class is building properly.

For example if I just type some random stuff in the middle of a class declaration like:

```
@class MyOtherClass;

@interface MyClass :  NSManagedObject  
{    !!!!!!!THIS SHOULD CAUSE A SYNTAX ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * myDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * myNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* otherEntities;

@end
```

it builds successfully. I have no idea why.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the custom class' .m file in the target you're building? It should be listed in the editor detail pane if you click on the target in the Targets tagets group in Xcode.

Comment: Actually they are not. How do I add them? Never had to do that before.

Edit: just figured it out. Syntax erros showing now so it must be being compiled with all the other classes. Wonder why it did that, something to do with auto-generating the class from the data model perhaps. Thanks for speedy replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're including the .m and .h files in your project?

Comment: And the .m in your target. (The .h does not need to be in a target.)